# In Sinatra, how to make filters dependent of request method?

Tags: rest, sinatra

I've been using filters in Sinatra the way it has been declared in the documentation: with no match string, with a match string or with a match regexp. It has been working fine til now. Now, I have a particular use case. Let's say I have this route:

```
/resources/1
```

According to REST, and depending of the request method, this can either be a GET method, PUT method or DELETE method. First question is: How to write filters that are only called when it is a GET request? (currently I'm letting all of them get filtered and only then I test the method. It works, but I don't like it). Second question, and more important: let's say a PUT request like this is triggered:

```
/resources/
```

This is of course wrong, because the PUT request has no resource id associated. I would like to know if there is something in Sinatra that enables me to do something like this:

```
before "/resources/", :method => :put do
  error_message
end
```

just this possibility does not exist (before accepts only one argument). How could I achieve this result at best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, filters [do take conditions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters). You don't have to use a condition though, you could use a conditional within the filter:

```
before "/path/" do
  if request.request_method == "PUT"
    # do something
  end
end
```

If you want to use a condition, I think you'll need to write one, perhaps something like this:

```
set(:accepted_verbs) {|*verbs|
  condition { 
    verbs.any?{|v| v == request.request_method }
  } 
}

before "/path/", :accepted_verbs => ["GET","POST"] do
  # do something
end

before "/path/", :accepted_verbs => ["PUT"] do
  # do something else
end
```

See [conditions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Conditions) for more.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I actually used your suggestion, but instead of defined such helpers methods as get?, post?, etc... but it basically does go into the request_method var.